# Unable to enable network adapter

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, drivers, powershell

The device doesn't show up in Device manager, despite restarting the PC, re-installing the drivers and trying Network reset and troubleshooting in settings. Still the device doesn't show up.

This is a laptop, ASUS TUF505DD-AL062T

In the past I had disabled the network driver with `wmic`, and at some point the enable/disable commands below stopped working

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where ProductName="Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller" call enable
wmic path win32_networkadapter where ProductName="Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller"  call disable
```

Now I get

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic path win32_networkadapter where ProductName="Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller" call enable
Executing (\\LAPTOP-2MQ5TDJ8\root\cimv2:Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID="2")->enable()
ERROR:
Description = Invalid method Parameter(s)
```

Or in power shell, similar result:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $wmi = gwmi win32_networkadapter -filter 'DeviceId = 2'
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> echo $wmi


ServiceName      :
MACAddress       :
AdapterType      :
DeviceID         : 2
Name             : Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
NetworkAddresses :
Speed            :




PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $wmi.Enable()
Exception calling "Enable" : "Invalid method Parameter(s) "
At line:1 char:1
+ $wmi.Enable()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException
```

Comment: Which model is your computer?

Comment: WMI isn't magic.  It just taps into the native APIs.  If the device manager doesn't see a device, WMI isn't a way around that.  You really didn't give much information to help you.  Is it a desktop or laptop?  If desktop, have you tried pulling and re-seating the card?  You might simply have a failed device.

Comment: See if going here https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software and then downloading and running the `Win10 Auto Installation Program (NDIS)`  or the `Win11 Auto Installation Program (NetAdapterCx)` helps. If there's an Asus diagnostics, you might run it too. Check and confirm you have not disabled this in your BIOS settings too before chasing too hard just in case it's turned off at the firmware level, the OS wouldn't be able to see it.